# How to express the relationship between java.time.LocalDate, DateTimeFormatter, String with UML

Tags: uml, java-time

In Java 8, `java.time.LocalDate.format(DateTimeFormatter formatter)` returns a `String` representing the `LocalDate` with the given `formatter`; reciprocally, the `static` method `java.time.LocalDate.parse(CharSequence text)` returns a `LocalData` object.

*Class diagram* or *object diagram* seems not to be able to express the relationship between the `String` and the `LocalDate` as there is no way to indicate which method is called to return each other.

My question is: **Is it possible to express the relationship between LocalDate, DateTimeFormatter and String that LocalDate can call `format` to get the String representation etc.?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not express dynamical behavior in a static class diagram. The only thing you can express here is the dependency. So you would draw a dependency from `LocalDate` to `String` and `DateTimeFormatter`.

To show any call sequence you would create a sequence diagram.